# how to create pivot query for this result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, pivot

I got result from query:

```
TITAL   PCS RGH_CTS    VALUE
-----   --- -------    ------------ 
SEND    10  49.8550    198742.94400
BID     15  76.7070    327461.76300
FINAL   19  88.5630    337954.15600
```

I want this output  - How to solve this?

```
| TITAL     |    SEND      |    BID       |   FINAL      |
----------------------------------------------------------
| PCS       |     10       |    15        |     19       |
| RGH_CTS   |   49.8550    |  76.7070     |   88.5630    |
| VALUE     | 198742.94400 | 327461.76300 | 337954.15600 |
```

Any body can solve this simple query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Combine `Pivot` and `Unpivot` to get the result.

First `Unpivot` the table to get the data in single column using `Cross Apply`.

Next `Pivot` the result of previous step to get the result.

```
SELECT Tital, 
       [SEND],
       [BID],
       [FINAL]
FROM   (SELECT t.TITAL AS tt,
               c.TITAL,
               cdata
        FROM   Tablename t
               CROSS apply ( VALUES ('PCS',[PCS]),
                                    ('RGH_CTS',[RGH_CTS]),
                                    ('VALUE',VALUE) ) c (TITAL, cdata)) a
       PIVOT (Max(cdata)
             FOR tt IN([SEND],
                       [BID],
                       [FINAL])) piv
```

### [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d986/1)

Comment: Thanks. its very use full yr suggestion. i got my result .. but in yr query i cant understood how to user 'cdata' from table. can you little explain this point .

Answer (score 0):

As per NoDisplayName, you'll need a do a full transpose, by first UNPIVOT ing, and then re-PIVOTing the data. You can also UNPIVOT data with the keyword with the same name:

```
SELECT Criteria as TITAL, [SEND], [BID], [FINAL]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        Result
    UNPIVOT 
    (
       SomeColumn
       for Criteria in (PCS, RGH_CTS, VALUE)
    ) unpvt

) X
PIVOT
(
   SUM(SomeColumn)
   for [TITAL] IN ([SEND], [BID], [FINAL])
)pvt;
```

Note that it is fairly unusual to retain the LHS column name after a Transpose (i.e. `TITAL` seems to refer to a different subject entirely in the pre and post transposed data)?

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b84030/9)

Comment: Query looks fine just a small suggestion this will not work if `PCS` is of different data type from `RGH_CTS`. If `PCS` is Int and `RGH_CTS` is of numeric then you may get `type conflict in unpivot list`. Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55a8f/2

Comment: Yes, good point, in which case the unpivoted data would need to be stored in the lowest common denominator (DECIMAL) and then re-cast back to INT in the final rePIVOT.

Comment: Yes thats the idea :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you're in SQL Server 2005+ you can use [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.100).aspx)

edit: I posted this before he had edited the question, making it more clear.